# How to convert or filter a comma-numbered elements in a data to number as elements in filtered data?

Tags: data, filtering, dataset

My subset data (10 Rows, 3 Columns) of the big data looks like this:

```
rawData = {{1, "19,33,818", "27,47,390"}, {2, "8,97,533", "15,78,537"}, {3, 
 "7,96,081", "24,54,991"}, {4, "1,42,029", "10,37,948"}, {5, 79545, 
 "10,71,860"}, {6, 17011, "8,57,758"}, {7, 16415, "6,53,447"}, {8, 
 25964, "10,08,842"}, {9, 2067, "4,88,400"}, {10, 903, "4,62,153"}};
```

The problem is in filtering this data to get pure numbered data without any commas in any element of it. Something like this:

```
{{1, 1933818, 2747390}, {2, 897533, 1578537},...}
```

Comment: Yes, I do agree

Comment: Upvoting wouldn't be a bad idea though ... 

Answer (score 2):

## [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html)

```
MapAt[
    If[
        Head[#]===String
        , ToExpression[StringDelete[","][#]]
        , #
    ]&
    , rawData
    , {All,{2,3}}
]
```

## [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`/.`)

```
rawData /.{s_String:>ToExpression[StringDelete[s, ","]]}
```